# rsync follow links and and use recreate path of the file the link points to in dest

Tags: linux, rsync, symbolic-link

I have a directory of symlinks A/ pointing to actual files in dir contents/.

Symlinks in A/ can be deleted but files in contents/ are never deleted.
For example
A/ looks like:

```
A/
 --B/ 
   --link1 -> contents/file1.txt<br/>
 --C/
   --link2 -> contents/file3.txt<br/>
```

contents/ looks like:

```
contents/
  --file1.txt
  --file2.txt
  --file3.txt
  --file4.txt
```

So files in contents might not be linked by anyone.
I would like to use rsync to sync both directories, but only transferring files that are actually pointed by links. I.e. transfer file1.txt and file3.txt.
I would like to use rsync to transfer the links in A/ following links and replacing the link names in the dest with the path of the file pointed to.

```
rsync --link A/* dest/
```

And end up with:

```
dest/
  --contents/
    --file1.txt
    --file3.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to do this purely with rsync, but rather with a combination for find and rsync.
First I created a snapshot of the contents dir with by doing

```
find  A/ -type l -exec readlink  {} \;
```

Then I created a content.snapshot dir where I created a symlink pointing to the file under contents in the content.snapshot directory for each of the files returned by the find command.

Finally i rsynced the content.snapshot dir instead of the contents dir. Enabling file deletion and link following in the rsync command.

The dir structure looks like this:

```
contents/
  --file1.txt
  --file2.txt
  --file3.txt
  --file4.txt

contents.snapshot/
  --contents/
    --file1.txt -> ../../contents/file1.txt
    --file3.txt -> ../../contents/file3.txt
```